# Redmine docker container not writing logs inside container

Tags: docker, containers, redmine

I am running a docker image of redmine that built myself using official docker image - version 4.2.10-passenger. Everything works perfect including mail. Only issue is it is not writing production.log in the default location inside the container - /usr/src/redmine/log. And I can not save the logs into a persistent volume as it is not available inside the container. I checked everywhere inside the container as I can. Is there any special configuration to enable log in redmine container. Please help !

I tried "docker logs my-redmine-container" and it shows log. I tried "docker logs -f my-redmine-container" and gives live log. But could not find it inside the default log folder and so could not bind it with a volume.